# How do I sum a dynamic list in C#?

Tags: c#, excel, visual-studio, epplus

Using the below block of code, how can I write a sum formula when the number of rows may change each time?  I have it hardcoded to sum C11:C33 and D11:D33 but I'm trying to move away from that. I know I can call the first and last values and use that as a range, but I'm struggling with the syntax.
Very new to this so apologies/thanks in advance!

```
using (FulfillmentEntities DB3 = new FulfillmentEntities())
                            { 
                                TotalRows = results5.Count();

                                foreach (var d in results5)
                                {
                                    int col = 2;

                                    worksheet.Cells[row, col++].Value = d.Category;
                                    worksheet.Cells[row, col++].Value = d.intA;
                                    worksheet.Cells[row, col++].Value = d.intB;

                                    row++;

                                }
                                int TotalCol = 2;

                                worksheet.Cells[row, TotalCol++].Value =  "Total";
                                worksheet.Cells[row, TotalCol++].Formula = "SUM(C11:C33)";
                                worksheet.Cells[row, TotalCol++].Formula = "SUM(D11:D33)";
                            }
```

Comment: Why not just make the formula something like worksheet.Cells[row, TotalCol++].Formula =  "SUM("+startColRow+":"+endColRow+")"

Comment: @AlexKrupka this is exactly what I'm looking for, but I don't know how to store the col/row values into startColRow/endColRow.

Comment: Can you clarify. Are you struggling with the assignment of the variables (how to pass these variables around) or with figuring out which cells are active in the excel doc?

Comment: @AlexKrupka I've figured out how to map the value to the correct cell, what I'm struggling with is the variable assignment.  For example, how does my program know that startColRow is the first row and that endColRow is the last?  I tried passing the range into a list and calling First() and Last() but it didn't work

Comment: Using `col++` like that seems to be asking for trouble. Why not use `col`, `col + 1`, and `col + 2`? And can't you do `worksheet.Cells[row, TotalCol++].Formula = String.Format("SUM(C11:C{0})", TotalRows + 11 - 1)`?

Comment: @Enigmativity I want to avoid any cell-specific hardcoding because I don't know that my first row will be C11.  There is another dynamic table above this one and depending on how many rows are in that one, it could change where this table starts.  Using col++ seems easier to me because I can keep it as a continuous variable.  But honestly, for the most part I have no idea what I'm doing

Comment: @EthanE - Then something like `worksheet.Cells[row, TotalCol++].Formula = String.Format("SUM(C{0}:C{1})", StartingRow, TotalRows + StartingRow - 1)`.

Answer (score 0):

Simply pass the list to the GetRowMinAndMax method. This method assumes that the list is not null or empty and that youre looking for a range in a single column

```
public Tuple<string,string> GetRowMinAndMax(List<string> colRows)
{
   var rowLow = colRows.Min(ExtractRow);
    var rowMax = colRows.Max(ExtractRow);
    var col = ExtractCol(colRows.First());
    return Tuple.Create(col + rowLow, col + rowMax);
}

public int ExtractRow(string colRow)
{
  return int.Parse(new string(colRow.Where(char.IsDigit).ToArray()));
}

public string ExtractCol(string colRow)
{
    return new string(colRow.Where(char.IsLetter).ToArray());
}
```

*EDIT*

Actually this all probably an over complication since its not across columns. The reason why list.First() doesn't work is because the list is not ordered so you're taking out the first element you put in. You could prob just order the list by calling

```
var orderedList = list.orderBy(s=> s);
```

then first and last would work.

Answer (score 0):

Just saw your edit Alex, thanks for all your help.  The tuple solution was a little over my head.  Below is what I wound up doing that worked perfectly and was very concise.  Created a variable for what I wanted my total to be, and incremented it with each row iteration using the += operator.  Then just called it outside of my foreach loop.

```
                           int? totalClientURL = 0;   
                           int? totalHgURL = 0;
                                foreach (var d in results5)
                                {
                                    int col = 6;

                                    worksheet.Cells[row, col++].Value = d.employees_range;
                                    worksheet.Cells[row, col].StyleName = styleData;
                                    worksheet.Cells[row, col++].Value = d.client_url_count;
                                    totalClientURL += d.client_url_count;
                                    worksheet.Cells[row, col].StyleName = styleData;
                                    worksheet.Cells[row, col++].Value = d.url_count;
                                    totalHgURL += d.url_count;


                                    row++;

                                    ExportCount++;
                                    if (ExportCount % 100 == 0)
                                        Worker.ReportProgress(20, ExportCount + " rows exported of " + TotalRows);
                                }

                                int TotalCol = 6;
                                worksheet.Cells[row, TotalCol++].Value = "Total";
                                worksheet.Cells[row, TotalCol].StyleName = styleData;
                                worksheet.Cells[row, TotalCol++].Value = totalClientURL;
                                worksheet.Cells[row, TotalCol].StyleName = styleData;
                                worksheet.Cells[row, TotalCol++].Value = totalHgURL;
```